# I want to show a message while fetching results

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have this JavaScript code to search my DB and to show results. I want to to show a message "*please wait..*" while fetching results. I have written that in line 3 (from last).

I mean, I want to show "*please wait...*" message in my search-results div while getting the results. But it is not showing any message.

```
function ajaxFunction(e) {
    function r() {
        if (t.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("search-results").innerHTML = t.responseText;
            document.getElementById("msg").style.display = "none"
        }
    }
    var t;
    try {
        t = new XMLHttpRequest
    } catch (n) {
        try {
            t = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } catch (n) {
            try {
                t = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (n) {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    var i = "search.php";
    i = i + "?name=" + e;
    i = i + "&sid=" + Math.random();
    t.onreadystatechange = r;
    t.open("GET", i, true);
    t.send(null);
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Please Wait ...";
    document.getElementById("msg").style.display = "inline"
}
```

Problem Solved

**UPDATE.**

I want to do this job only when the input reaches 10 characters.

**HTML CODE**

```
<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="10" id="name" onkeyup="ajaxFunction(this.value);" />
```

Comment: Does an element with ID `msg` actually exist? I think you can solve this problem yourself if you learn [how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think you need to add somthing to the r():

```
if (t.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("search-results").innerHTML = t.responseText;
            document.getElementById("msg").style.display = "none"
        }

if (t.readyState == 1 ||t.readyState == 2 ||t.readyState == 3) {         
            document.getElementById("msg").style.display = "block";
        }
```

....so that it is shown while connecting/receiving/prossesing. You might not have hidden it before, but any messesages for following requests would not get shown

Comment: thanks this solved my problem :) i have another problem too. i want to run this script only when the input reaches 10 characters. can you help me in this too..

Comment: not rearranging your code, that could be accomplished with onkeyup="if(this.value.length>9){ajaxFunction(this.value)}"

Answer (score 1):

well what you can try is also to show a display before calling the ajax function and hide it when the ajax request is already finish

```
 //show the message
 document.getElementById("msg").style.display = "inline" 
 //call the ajax function
 ajaxFunction(e);
```

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. The Ajax request is asynchronous, so it's fine to show the message when the request was just sent.

Comment: @mahen a plus one for you. it didn't helped me. but it gave me an idea. thank you. b/w i have updated the question. please check it ones